# https with Apache 2.2.17 is very slow

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I have two servers 1) sun one iplanet 6.1 & 2) apache 2.2.17

If I use stress test tool like JMEter, I got very slow response for Apache but it I use the same URL for sun one web server, it seems really fast. Can anybody suggest what I need to tune in config side. This shouldn't be problem with OS settings as sun one server on the same machine is working very fine.

I am using worker mpm

    ServerLimit          25
    StartServers         10
    MaxClients          525
    MinSpareThreads      50
    MaxSpareThreads     300
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestsPerChild  5000

Also, Keep alive is set as ON and time out set as 2 sec.

Please help me to go further. My feeling is something is not right in the configuration side. I am just trying to use simple hello world html file.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `openssl s_client -connect 1.2.3.4:443` (where 1.2.3.4 should be the IP address or hostname of your server) against each server. Specifically, note the ciphersuite in use. It's printed at the end like: `Cipher    : RC4-SHA`.

If the Apache server is running a DHE (aka EDH) ciphersuite while the other server is not, then that'll explain the difference. Consult standard modssl documents for configuring a ciphersuite.